# Number of active user sessions in an OpenERP server

Tags: performance, monitoring, odoo

How can I find the number of "active sessions" in my OpenERP server ?

I'm aware that "active sessions" is not an exact concept here, but overall what I would like to be aware of is the level of usage stress the server is being subject to, and comparing that to the OS resources being dedicated to the process.

Comment: good question. I think you will need a tool like new relic to give you a picture on this

Answer (score 1):

I added a small amount of logging code to the server to trace the user id, model, and a few other parameters for each request that came through. You need to be careful not to record anything sensitive like passwords, and you should be careful that your tracing doesn't add a significant load to the server. You can see the tracing code we added to OpenERP 5 [on launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-server/main/view/2011/bin/netsvc.py#L473).

If you don't need the same level of detail, it would probably add less load to use a network sniffer to count connections to OpenERP's port, as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/11725/3986).